# Defining an Excel Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to define 2 ranges in 2 seperate workbooks and manipulate the data.  However when I define the range below:

```
SAPBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
SAPSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

SAPRange = Workbooks(SAPBook).Worksheets(SAPSheet).Range("A:A")

SAPRange.Select
```

The range is nothing and nothing gets selected.  So I thought maybe I wasn't being explicit enough in my select call, but the below will select nothing as well.

```
Workbooks(SAPBook).Worksheets(SAPSheet).Range(SAPRange).Select
```

If I don't define my range and use the following everything works just fine.

```
Workbooks(SAPBook).Worksheets(SAPSheet).Range("A:A").Select
```

Why can't I define my range and select the Range?  What am I missing here?  I'm sure it's something easy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Set` keyword:

```
Set SAPRange = Workbooks(SAPBook).Worksheets(SAPSheet).Range("A:A")
```

Comment: I promise I tried this at one point.  My code had must of been broken further down and I must have fixed it and not went back and tried it again.  Thanks!  Why can I define my Book and sheet without using set?

Comment: Nevermind I understand it now.  I'm not really defining a workbook or Worksheet object.  I'm just defining a string so SET isn't required because it's not an object definition.  BAH I feel stupid sometimes ><